# iPhone 4 signing in issues

Tags: iphone

So I just got my iPhone and I made a new Apple iTunes account and I verified my account through email then I tried to download a game and it says please sign in so I tried signing it and it said I need to complete my registration and to put in bank details , which I already did signing up... so I put them in again and this time it came back with " card declined, payment method didn't work" blah blah blah..

I cannot download games and I cannot access my emails or apples iTunes I cannot sign in it wot let me can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to solve this is to call Apple Care (http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201232). They would be able to solve this if you want to download an app.

When you want to download a free app, you could also try on iTunes for a Mac of windows pc. When you're asked to enter your payment credentials, there should be an option to choose "none". I would try this first before calling Apple Care.